# How to access values from settings.bundle?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, settings.bundle

I am doing a project where I have to retrieve some values in settings.bundle. For this I have to retrieve a default value in such a manner.
I am accessing it as under

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

stringObject = [defaults objectForKey:@"Key_Value"];
```

But when I try to print stringObject

```
NSLog(@"%@",stringObject);
```

Then it always print null.
I have saved a string value in the settings.bundle with key "Key_Value". But It returns Null.

tell me where I am doing wrong

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to retrieve values from settings.bundle in objective c?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291477/how-to-retrieve-values-from-settings-bundle-in-objective-c)

Comment: Please post code showing how you set the value initially. Also, remember to synchronize UserDefaults after settings values.

Answer (score 2):

check you have stored you value in this way:-

```
NSUserDefaults *pref3=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [pref3 setObject:*yourstring* forKey:@"Key_Value"];
    [NSUserDefaults resetStandardUserDefaults];
```

your code of retreiving is correct.make sure stringObject is of NSString type.

Comment: @sanchitsingh I am curious to know whether your problem is sorted out or not.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. He stores the data in Settings.bundle [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291477/how-to-retrieve-values-from-settings-bundle-in-objective-c) you can find out what was the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

Call this function will resolve your issue

```
- (void)registerDefaultsFromSettingsBundle {
     // this function writes default settings as settings
     NSString *settingsBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"bundle"];
    if(!settingsBundle) {
       NSLog(@"Could not find Settings.bundle");
       return;
    }

    NSDictionary *settings = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[settingsBundle stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Root.plist"]];
    NSArray *preferences = [settings objectForKey:@"PreferenceSpecifiers"];

    NSMutableDictionary *defaultsToRegister = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithCapacity:[preferences count]];
    for(NSDictionary *prefSpecification in preferences) {
    NSString *key = [prefSpecification objectForKey:@"Key"];
    if(key) {
        [defaultsToRegister setObject:[prefSpecification objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"] forKey:key];
        NSLog(@"writing as default %@ to the key %@",[prefSpecification objectForKey:@"DefaultValue"],key);
    }

   [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] registerDefaults:defaultsToRegister];

}
```