# iOS Settings.bundle dictionaryForKey

Tags: ios, nsuserdefaults

Is there any option to display in iOS Settings.bundle not only standard NSUserDefaults but also for a specific key. I would like to have the serverURL setting displayed inside iOS Settings app.

```
static NSString * const kConfigurationKey = @"com.apple.configuration.managed";
static NSString * const kConfigurationServerURLKey = @"serverURL";

NSDictionary *serverConfig = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryForKey:kConfigurationKey];
NSString *serverURLString = serverConfig[kConfigurationServerURLKey];
```

I would like to avoid copying it from this dictionary to the main one just to have it displayed.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6291477/how-to-retrieve-values-from-settings-bundle-in-objective-c

Comment: Mean you would like to show list acknowledgements in you app setting?

Comment: It won't help. I don't know how to reference com.apple.configuration.managed -> serverURL in the Settings.bundle. I could add a piece of code that copies the value directly to the NSUserDefaults but I would like to avoid it.