# How can I implement a generic struct that manages key-value pairs for UserDefaults in Swift?

Tags: swift, generics, data-structures, struct

How would one implement a struct that manages UserDefaults mappings in Swift?
Right now I have some computed properties a, b, c, d of different types and corresponding keys that look like this:

```
enum UserDefaultsKeys {
    a_key
    b_key
    ...
}
var a: String {
    get { UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.a_key.rawValue) }
    set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.a_key.rawValue) }
}
var b: Int {
    get { UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.b_key.rawValue) }
    set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.b_key.rawValue) }
}
...
```

What I would like to achieve instead is to implement a struct that has a key of type String and a generic type value.
The value get function should - depending on its type - chose wether to use `UserDefaults.standard.string` or `UserDefaults.standard.integer` so that I can just create a DefaultsVar with some key and everything else is managed automatically for me.
What I have so far is this:

```
struct DefaultsVar<T> {
    let key: String
    var value: T {
        get {
            switch self {
                case is String: return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: key) as! T
                case is Int: return UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: key) as! T
                default: return UserDefaults.standard.float(forKey: key) as! T
            }
        }
        set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: key) }
    }
}
```

I get the following error: "Cast from DefaultsVar to unrelated Type 'String' always fails.
I am completely new to swift (and relatively new to programming) and don't really understand how to implement this the right way - or if this is even an approach that would be considered a good practice. Could someone please shine some light on this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: What is the benefit? The setter of `UserDefaults` **is** already generic and there are only a few supported types.

Comment: I thought it might prevent some boilerplate code for all the variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a custom

#### Property wrapper:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefaultStorage<T: Codable> {
    private let key: String
    private let defaultValue: T

    private let userDefaults: UserDefaults

    init(key: String, default: T, store: UserDefaults = .standard) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = `default`
        self.userDefaults = store
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            guard let data = userDefaults.data(forKey: key) else {
                return defaultValue
            }
            let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)
            return value ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(newValue)
            userDefaults.set(data, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

This wrapper can store/restore **any kind of codable** into/from the user defaults.

#### Usage

```
@UserDefaultStorage(key: "myCustomKey", default: 0)
var myValue: Int
```

---

## iOS 14

SwiftUI has a similar wrapper (only for iOS 14) called `@AppStorage` and it can be used as a state. The advantage of using this is that it can be used directly as a `State`. But it requires `SwiftUI` and it only works from the iOS 14.

Comment: There is no need to cast from `Any` to `Data`. `UserDefaults` has a specific method exactly to retrieve data from it. `data(forKey:)`.

Comment: Yeah, you are right @LeoDabus. I should update my gist :) Thanks

Comment: Great! Thank you for your answer! One question though: is it really preferable to return a default value (thus hiding mistakes that might have been made) instead of throwing an error if no value can be returned?

Comment: The class itself always returns a default value. By the way, we are talking about user **Defaults** right? ;)

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget the **upvote** if it was helpful and **accept** if it was the answer to you ;)

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini `return (try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data)) ?? defaultValue` Btw you can move the decoding part to the guard as well

Comment: `guard let data = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: key), let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(T.self, from: data) else { return defaultValue }` `return value`

Comment: I'm not a fan of writing everything in a single line. I tried to separate parts of that, so anyone can raise assertions for example ‍♂️. Thanks for your care :)